# new JSONArray(String[]) on Android

Tags: java, android, json, api

I'm trying to create a JSONArray in a file that is in a linked Folder to a Android Project, and eclipse is suddenly (didn't do this before) giving me the error : 
 Call requires API level 19 (current min is 14): new org.json.JSONArray

the code where it happens is as following:

```
String[] s = (save_val.trim().equals(""))?new String[]{}:save_val.split("\n");
JSONObject o = null;
if (!Arrays.equals(s, save_names)){

    new JSONArray(s); // this is where the error is shown
```

EDIT: SOLUTION the method in fact isn't introduced before API 19, but if you use (as in my case) String array or other promitives you can simply do:

```
    JSONArray s_values = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        s_values.put(yourarray[i]);
    }
```

this shouldn't be any slower

Comment: Seems like your SDK version is off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the constructor `JSONArray(Object array)` was not introduced until **API level 19**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object)

You can change your min **API** version in your `manifest` to be 19 or

you can convert your `Object array` to a `Collection array` like `ArrayList` and use the Collection array constructor of `JSONArray` which is available from   **API 1**.

Good Luck!

Comment: DejanRistic is right. Just bear in mind that `jsonObject.put("xyz", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(floatArray)))` will give you an array containing your e.g. float array (`{ "xyz": [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]] }`), while `JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(); for (float value : floatArray) { arr.put(value); }; jsonObject.put("xyz", arr)` would in turn provide you just with an array, as you'd expect (`{ "xyz": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] }`).

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing the JSONArray with an array of strings, which according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.Object%29) is only available in API level 19 or higher. You'll either need to use an alternative constructor or change the minimum API level to 19 in your manifest to make the constructor available.

Comment: where can i see the level in which this was introduced (in the documentation)? (just found it, small on the right side of the grey method declaration)

Comment: If you look in the grey title bar with the method name in it, the API level it was added in is on the right-hand side :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternative constructor by providing a collection. This will create an JSONArray by copying all values given in the collection.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(collection);
```